# Python: Creating a new dataframe that only contains rows from a specified array of index numbers

Tags: python, dataframe

I have an array of index numbers [10,12,15,...33], called `index_array`, and a dataframe, called `df`,that has multiple rows and columns.
I want to create a second dataframe, called `newdf`, that only has the rows [10,12,15,...33] but must contain all the original columns.

I've tried:

```
newdf = []
if index_array[0] == df.index[0]:
   newdf.append(df[0])
```

*this is inside a loop that will check all the index_array values against the dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, the solution is simply `df.iloc[index_array]`.

Comment: @timgeb what is  IIUC?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be with `loc[]`:

```
new_df = df.loc[index_arrays,:]
```

The first part of half is the row names (index values) and the second part `:` basically selects all columns